# Event Sourcing and total aggregates encapsulation

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I came across that Event Sourcing assumes total encapsulation. Aggregates dosen`t allow to access their internal state. State is internaly kept only to impose valid transions. As far as I grasp this aggregates (in terms of outside world) just emits events. And I cant get my head around that actualy. I refine my models to reflect my bussiness needs which leads to objects that publish some API. For example, I have two aggregate roots: cart and order. I would like to build my order using ActiveItems from cart:

`$order->addItems($cart->getActvieItems)`

But this violates ES assumtion about total encapsulation of aggregate state. How order should be fulfilled with ActiveItmes according to ES good practices? Should I use read model? I think this leads to knowleadge leak out of the model (aggregate). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Alexey is right in that the Event Sourcing is just a persistence mechanism. I think the confusion comes when thinking about Aggregates. Encapsulation is an important concept when thinking about Aggregates. The implication here is that they are not used for query or the UI. Hence the reason CQRS fits in so well.

But most applications need to query the data or display things on the UI. And that's where Read Models come in handy. Assuming you are using CQRS and Event Sourcing (which you don't have to when using Aggregates) it's a fairly easy thing to do. The idea is to subscribe to the events and update the Read Model as you go. This doesn't 'leak' anything because the functionality is in the Aggregate domain objects.

Why is this a good thing?

1. Have no or extremely limited dependencies makes the aggregate's much simpler to work with.
2. Read models can be highly optimised for reading from and therefore very fast.
3. Read models don't require complex queries and joins.
4. There is a clear separation of concerns
5. This approach offers huge scaling potential
6. It's easy to test

I'm sure there are more. If it helps I have a blog post outlining a typical CQRS and ES architecture. You may find it helpful. You can find it here: [CQRS + Event Sourcing – A Step by Step Overview](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/)

Comment: A perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Event Sourcing does not assume anything in addition to the fact that you save the state of your object as series of events. There is even no requirements to have an "aggregate" when doing Event Sourcing.

If you are talking about the DDD terms *Aggregate* and *Aggregate Root*, again, Event Sourcing is just a way to save the object as a stream of events instead of the last actual state. There are no additionally imposed "requirements" like "total encapsulation" and inaccessibility of the internal state. Of course aggregates (and other objects) have state.

What could be confusing is that if you also use CQRS, you can have your aggregate state not being used since all its data is transient to the read model. But this is something else and does not need to be blindly applied.

Again, Event Sourcing is just a persistence method, nothing more, and nothing less.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I thoroughly agree with all you said. But according do "red book" (Vaugh Vernon - Implementign DDD) there should not be any getters in the aggregate. It is mentioned expicitly like that: "by design aggregates dont have any query methods (getters). As a result, we need another way to query, which generally leads to employing CQRS". Wikipedia states like this: "as the aggregate root comprehensively hides its internal state." That is why I am confused :)

Comment: Any *query* methods means that you cannot ask your aggregate to give you the list of aggregates by some crazy filter. Aggregate cares about itself only, being a transaction boundary and consistency boundary. But it does not mean that the `User` aggregate cannot have a `getName`. Event-sourced aggregates are not different from "regular" aggregates in this sense. Event-sourcing does not set additional restrictions on the aggregate design, except all its command methods need to emit events and only event handlers can change the aggregate state.

Answer (score 1):

> $order->addItems($cart->getActvieItems)

In addition to the comprehensive coverage of CQRS in the answers, I'd like to point out that in the message driven systems commands(messages) should be self-contained and have all information encapsulated necessary to perform the action.

In the above example, `Order` aggregate receives command `AddItems` with the list of `Items` `Ids` as a payload. The fact that `AddItems` command handler needs to get additional information to handle the command points to a problem. `AddItems` command has no sufficient payload so `Cart` and `Order` are semantically coupled. You would want to avoid that.

Message passing reasoning is the key here. Here are some abstractions

```
class AddItems : Command
{
   List ItemIds {get; set;}
}
class Order
{
   void AddItems(AddItems command){}
}
```

Comment: That is all correct but has little to do with *EventSourcing* :)

Comment: @sergiy-chernets thank you. Your post is really helpfull. But how to build this command? I mean the list/collection of items. Can I get it from cart aggregate?
```$cart->getActiveItems()
```
Because as far as I understand ES it  assumes comprehensive encapsulation. So should I get this from read side? Or maybe I misunderstood the encapsulation concept?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I agree with you. Even though the context of the question is EventSorcing it has nothing to do with it either. My answer did not claim that it was. :)

Comment: @ayeo, It is a very good and important question. Where does command originate? You guessed it in the right direction. It is all about your DDD model. If the command originates from the human interaction/UI, all information needed would come from the _Read Model_ of the _Cart_. If not, then it may be the reaction to a specific event that will contain the necessary information. In some cases, you would need to get extra information to handle the command, however, it probably would be the case for the _Process Manager_ pattern. In _Actor Model_ world, these problems are solved more naturally.